# displaying image in php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I searched for the solutions but they didn't work! 
I am trying to show the image that is in my database [in Eventss table] the row is called image and it is BLOB format.
This is the page where the data will be displayed for people and I am focusing on the php know and I will fix the if condition after figuring out how to show the image.

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("***", "***", "***")
or die("<p>Error connecting to database: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");

mysql_select_db("project")
or die("<p>Error selecting the database ectoday: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");

session_start();
$select_query = "SELECT * FROM Eventss WHERE id=". $_SESSION["event_id"];
$result = mysql_query($select_query);
if($result) 
    { 
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {   
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo $row['title']. "<br>";
                if ($row['image'] !== NULL)
                {
                    $poster =  $row['image'];
                    echo $row['content']. "<br>";
                    echo $row['event_date']. "  [" . $row['event_time']. "]"."<br>";
                    echo $row['location']. "<br>";
                }
                else
                {
                echo $row['content']. "<br>";
                echo $row['event_date']. "  [" . $row['event_time']. "]"."<br>";
                echo $row['location']. "<br>";
                }

            }   
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Sorry, there is no more data for this event";
        }
    }
 ?>
 <html>
 <head><head>
 <body>
    <img src="<?php echo $poster; ?>" width="175" height="200" />
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: so what exactly doesn't work?, do you get errors?, is error_reporting on?, could your session be empty?, also, look into PDO prepared statements or MySQLi prepared statements while you're at it, your code is vulnerable to mysql injections

Comment: Where did you save the image? Any specific directory?

Answer (score 0):

If it's stored in a BLOB it's most likely the actual image data as binary, instead of a reference to an image on the filesystem. You will either have to write it to a file and display it using a standard img tag, or otherwise convert it to base64 (see [`base64_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php))...

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, HereGoesYourBase64fromBLOB..." />
```

...but be aware that base64-encoded image data may not be the most bandwidth-friendly solution. It's better to have static resources stored in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't store a path to that image, but the image content itself and that it is jpg (you can change to png or whatever type you have there). If so, use data URI syntax for src:

```
<img src="<?php 
echo 'data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($poster); ?>" width="175" height="200" />
```